# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - and I can't see where

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, codepen

I was making tip calculator and i got an error

```
function CalcTip(){
var bill = document.querySelector('#bill').value;
var people = document.querySelector('#people').value;
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var total = bill.value/people.value;                 
document.getElementById("#last").innerHTML = "$" + total;  
total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;

}
```

button.addEventListener('click',function(){} calcTip();
    );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several errors in your code.

Here is a functional example:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("calculate");
button.addEventListener('click', CalcTip);

function CalcTip(){
  var bill = document.getElementById('bill');
  var people = document.getElementById('people');  
  var total = parseInt(bill.value) / parseInt(people.value);                 
  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
  
  document.getElementById("last").innerHTML = "$" + total;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="calculate">Calc Tip</button><br>

<input type="text" id="bill"><br>
<input type="text" id="people">this can't be 0<br>

<div id="last"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is on your addEventListener, it should be

```
button.addEventListener('click', calcTip);
```

Comment: Or simply `button.addEventListener('click', calcTip);`

Comment: wow, answer after 45sec

Comment: One line make this coding issue.

Comment: Also, the `CalcTip` function is declared with an uppercase `C`, while it's referred to as `calcTip` in the event listener. JS is case-sensitive. By convention, a function that is not used as a constructor usually starts with a lowercase letter